# Upgraded to Mojave and now Webpack build fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, handlebars.js

After upgrading to Mojave, running `webpack --mode development` on my project now gives me the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/templates/contact-list-item.hbs
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/handlebars-loader/index.js):
/Users/username/Desktop/Project/Public/js/node_modules/loader-utils/lib/urlToRequest.js:7
    const moduleRequestRegex = /^[^?]*../../;
                                          ^
```

This error is repeated for each of my `.hbs` files.

I'm uncertain whether this is an npm problem or a webpack problem. I wonder what installing MacOS Mojave might have changed to break this. If anyone has any ideas I would be very grateful! :)

**Full stack trace**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:226:18)
at Module._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:172:36)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
at require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sammettam/Desktop/Vapor3Test/Public/js/node_modules/loader-utils/lib/index.js:8:22)
at Module._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
at require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sammettam/Desktop/Vapor3Test/Public/js/node_modules/handlebars-loader/index.js:1:81)
at Module._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
at require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
at loadLoader (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:13:17)
at iteratePitchingLoaders (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
at runLoaders (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
at NormalModule.doBuild (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:265:3)
at NormalModule.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:412:15)
@ ./src/features/contacts/contact-form.js 7:0-65 62:17-37
@ ./src/components/create-menu.js
@ ./src/app.js
```